# TreeSet storing duplicate custom objects

Tags: java, set, comparable

Hello I probably oversaw something, but here it goes.
I have a `TreeSet<CustomObject>` and I do not want to have duplicates in the Set. My `CustomObject` class looks like this.

```
class CustomObject implements Comparable<CustomObject> {

    String product;
    String ean;

    public CustomObject(String ean){
      this.ean = ean; 
      // product is getting set via setter and can be null
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        CustomObject that = (CustomObject) o;

        return ean.equals(that.ean);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ean.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CustomObject another) {
        if(equals(another)) return 0;
        if(product != null && another.product == null) return -1;
        if(product == null) return 1;

        return product.compareToIgnoreCase(another.product);
    }
}
```

Now I have a add Function for new objects.

```
private final TreeSet<CustomObject> productCatalog;

public void addObject(SomeData tag) {
    CustomObject p = new CustomObject(tag.getEan());

    if (productCatalog.contains(p)) { // <-- This checks only one entry of the Set.
        for (CustomObject temp : productCatalog) {
            if (temp.equals(p)) {
                p = temp; // I do stuff with that later which is irrelevent here
            }
        }
    } else {
       productCatalog.add(p);
    }   
}
```

The method `productCatalog.contains(p)` calls the `compareTo` method from the `Comparable` Interface and does the comparing. The issue here is that it literally only checks I think the last object? in the set. So what happens is that only one unique CustomObject entry is present.

This is the scenario when I follow it with the debugger:

1. `productCatalog.contains(p)`
2. calls `compareTo`
3. calls `equals` to check if `ean.equals(that.ean)`
4. returns once true, but every other time false. Since it only checks the last object

How can I have it to check not only one object in step 4, but all the present objects in the Set. What am I missing?

Thx!

---

EDIT: These are some sample data. For the simplicity `SomeData tag` is basically a String.

```
First run:

addObject("Ean1") // success added
addObject("Ean2") // success added
addObject("Ean3") // success added
addObject("Ean4") // success added
```

Everything gets added into the TreeSet.

```
Second run:
addObject("Ean1") // failed already in the map
addObject("Ean2") // failed already in the map
addObject("Ean3") // failed already in the map
addObject("Ean5") // success added
addObject("Ean4") // success added
addObject("Ean4") // success added
```

For testing purpose I manually set product names depending on the String `ean`.

```
public CustomObject(String ean){
      this.ean = ean; 
       switch(ean){
            case "Ean1": product = "TestProduct"; break;
            case "Ean2": product = "ProductTest";break;
            case "Ean3": product = "Product";break;
    }
```

The `TreeSet` acts as a cache.

---

Edit2: This is how I solved it.

```
            for (CustomObject temp : productCatalog) {
                if (temp.equals(p)) {
                    p = temp; // I do stuff with that later which is irrelevent here
                }
            }
```

I removed the if statement with the `contains` method since that would always return ´1`or`-1`in my special case. Now I simply iterate over the Set to correctly use the`equals` method since the TreeSet uses compareTo() for checking every element in the Set.

The Java Docs state the following

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a **TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method**, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the kind of wrong behaviour you get? Is there actually a "double element" in the set? What do you mean by "the last object"?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem:

`compareTo` does return 1 if both product and other.product are null. This is wrong because they are actually equal. You probably forgot to set product names for the higher ean values, like "Ean4" and "Ean5".

Old answer:

Your implementations of `equals` and `compareTo` do not fit together.

`equals` works on the ean and `compareTo` on the product. This only works if you implicitly assume that equal ean imply equal product. If this is not true in your test cases, the result will be wrong.

In either case, it is no good implementation because this can lead to a < b, b < c but a "equals" c.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The requirements were basically like that. A sorted list by productname and if no productname is available it should just be appended to the end of the list.

Comment: It was on purpose that Ean4 and Ean5 have no product name. These should be appended to the end of list which is actually working with the compareTo. The problem is with the `equals` method since it only checks for one single object in the Set. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: If you search for an element in the TreeSet "equals" is only applied if compareTo evaluates to 0. If compareTo evaluates to 1 or -1, it is assumed that elements are not equal. Therefore, it is essential that your compareTo implementation is compatible with your equals implementation.

Comment: This brought me actually onto the right track. I will post my solution shortly. Thanks!